# ActionScript 3.0 Getting Size/Coordinates From Loader Content

Tags: actionscript-3, get, size

i'm attempting to position a textfield to the bottom left of an image that is added to the display list from the Loader() class.  i don't know how to access the width/height information of the image.

```
var dragSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
this.addChild(dragSprite);

var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest("picture.jpg"));
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, displayPic, false, 0, true);

function displayPic(evt:Event):void
    {
    dragSprite.addChild(evt.target.content);
    evt.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, displayPic);
    }

var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = "Picture Title";
tf.width = 200;
tf.height = 14;
tf.x //same x coordinate of dragSprite
tf.y //same y coordinate of dragSprite, plus picture height, plus gap between picture and text

addChild(tf);
```

within the displayPic function, i could assign the evt.target.content.height and evt.target.content.width to variables that i could use to position the text field, but i assume there is a more appropriate and direct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way since you have to wait the image to be loaded to access `width`, and `height`.

But you can place you text as soon as the complete is done if it`s fit your design. Store the value into some var so you can reuse it when moving the sprite.

```
//...
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = "Picture Title";
tf.width = 200;
tf.height = 14;

addChild(tf);

var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest("picture.jpg"));
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
     Event.COMPLETE, displayPic, false, 0, true
);

var offsetX:Number=0;
var offsetY:Number=0;

function positionText():void {
  tf.x=dragSprite.x + offsetX;
  tf.y=dragSprite.y + offsetY;
}

function displayPic(evt:Event):void {
 var li:LoaderInfo=evt.target as LoaderInfo;

 if (li===null)
    return;

 li.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, displayPic);

 var dob:DisplayObject=li.content;
 if (dob!==null) {
  dragSprite.addChild(dob);

  // set only once the offset depending on the loaded image
  offsetX = ...//
  offsetY = dob.height+gap //...

  // position text using the offset setted
  // so you can reuse the function when moving your sprite
  positionText();
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. i was assuming that maybe i could have called the dragSprite's child and get the info from it, but this way seems just as well.

also, i spotted a small error in your example.  var dob:DisplayObject = evt.target.content as DisplayObject;, without content it doesn't work.  but besides that, according to the documentation the loader() class only loads display objects (images, swf's) so evaluating if it's a display object upon completion is redundant.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 Good catch, yes i forget it, thanks. Since your content is a child of dragSprite you can get information from there (after content is loaded), but since i don't know how it will be used, how many child in your drag sprite,etc... i just put the part based on the loaded content.